# I have an error when upload file to aws s3 bucket by using php

Tags: php, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

```
<?php

require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    $s3_config = array(
        'key' => '*************',
        'secret' => '*****************************');

    $s3 = S3Client::factory([
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => $s3_config['key'],
                'secret' => $s3_config['secret'],],
            'region' => 'ap-northeast-2',
            'version' => 'latest']);

    function uploadS3($bucket, $dir, $file) {

        $key = md5(uniqid());
        $type = mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']);
        $ext = explode('/', $type);
        $ext = $ext[sizeof($ext) - 1];
        $file_name = "{$key}.{$ext}";
        $file_path = "./files/{$file_name}";

        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $file_path);

        $save_path = null;

        try {

            $result = $GLOBALS['s3']->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key' => "{$dir}/{$file_name}",
                'Body' => fopen($file_path, 'rb'),
                'ACL' => 'public-read']);
            $save_path = $result['ObjectURL'];
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            // return null;
        }

        unlink($file_path);

        return $save_path;
    }

?>
```

This is my code
I have key and secret also.

I make this and try to upload Image File.

```
if (isset($_FILES['ImageOneAdd'])) {

            $ImageOneAdd = uploadS3('testbucket','image',$_FILES['ImageOneAdd']);

        }
```

but in postman, that returns this.

```
{
  "status": false,
  "error": {
    "classname": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "message": "Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutObject operation:\n[Body] must be an fopen resource, a GuzzleHttp\\Stream\\StreamInterface object, or something that can be cast to a string. Found bool(false)"
  }
}
```

I don't know why this problems occur.

I just do it with aws s3 upload php API;

If anyone look at this code, and any wrong for that, please help me

---

yes I chagne this code,

```
try {

            $result = $GLOBALS['s3']->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key' => "{$dir}/{$file_name}",
                'SourceFile' => $file_path,
                'ACL' => 'public-read']);
            $save_path = $result['ObjectURL'];
        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            // return null;
        }
```

but it occurs error with this.

```
{
  "status": false,
  "error": {
    "classname": "RuntimeException",
    "message": "Unable to open ./files/40c0a29b0599204c147745116554af59.jpeg using mode r: fopen(./files/40c0a29b0599204c147745116554af59.jpeg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Polaris.please try to upload image from directory instead of input file.so you can check issue with direct upload or not.

Comment: @iCoders I don't understand do you mean upload image from directory is file path>

Comment: try to upload one image from upload directory instead of  form input file so you can check that works or not

Comment: @iCoders I try to upload image file from directory, but it doesn't work

Comment: instead of reading the file, try to use file uploading functionality of S3. `'SourceFile' => $pathToFile,` ( http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html )

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading the file, Try to upload a file using below code.

```
    $result = $GLOBALS['s3']->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => $bucket,
        'Key'        => "{$dir}/{$file_name}",
        'SourceFile' => $file_path
    ));
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject

Comment: Thanks but..
I changed the code, but i occurs error

Comment: The file is not available on given path... That's why this error occurs.

The file must be available on given path after using move_uploaded_file.

Comment: Do you mean $file_path is the path which express the absolute path?

I develop the app, and I hope, when I post the file path, function uploadS3 will upload the file.

Comment: Yes, same thing